# git special characters on mac

Tags: git, macos, special-characters

I have a git repository with filenames like "Esbjörn.jpg".

These upload into git w/o issue, and I can clone the files fine. However running 'git status' after the clone on my mac will show the file as untracked.

I saw [this patch](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2010/5/20/30759), but as techie as I am, this is not an approach I want to dive into. Is there an easy way to get special characters, git, and snow leopard to work nicely together?

Thanks!
Peter

Comment: See also: [Git and the Umlaut problem on mac os x](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581857/git-and-the-umlaut-problem-on-mac-os-x).

Answer (score 0):

Use [EGit](http://eclipse.org/egit/), it handles them correctly.