# Git and the Umlaut problem on Mac OS X

Tags: git, macos, versioning

Today I discovered a bug for Git on Mac OS X.

For example, I will commit a file with the name überschrift.txt with the German special character Ü at the beginning. From the command `git status` I get following output.

```
Users-iMac: user$ git status

On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   "U\314\210berschrift.txt"
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

It seems that Git 1.7.2 has a problem with German special characters on Mac OS X.
Is there a solution to get Git read the file names correct?

Comment: See also [commit 3a59e59](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3a59e5954ef19ac94522219c2f29d49a187d31d8) (01 Jul 2015) by [Karsten Blees (`kblees`)](https://github.com/kblees).  
(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 81bc521](https://github.com/git/git/commit/81bc521af22a6549e93d33e57de40d335e0ee65b), 03 Aug 2015)

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Enable core.precomposeunicode on the mac

```
git config --global core.precomposeunicode true
```

For this to work, you need to have at least Git 1.8.2.

Mountain Lion ships with 1.7.5. To get a newer git either use [git-osx-installer](https://code.google.com/archive/p/git-osx-installer) or [homebrew](https://brew.sh) (requires Xcode).

That's it.

Comment: Is there a way to fix paths without re-cloning from the origin? I've cloned a rather large [git-annex](http://git-annex.branchable.com/) repo, with gigabytes of files.

Comment: While the size of the repo might not be important for this problem and fix, this particular repo contains tens of thousands of files and hundreds of revisions - I'd rather perform an in-place fix.

Comment: What's odd is that this /sort of/ works for me.  I have a large git-annex repo, and when I turn this on, /most/ of the git status noise goes away.  But not all of it.  :-/

Comment: It used to work perfectly when I wrote, but recently I too saw some bugs around this again.

Comment: Oddly, for me the _opposite_ worked (`git config --global core.precomposeunicode false`). I'm running OS X 10.9.2 and Git 1.8.5.2, with the files stored on a disk image with the HFS+ filesystem. Could it be that Apple changed their implementation?

Comment: Kudos @Philipp — that change did the trick. This would make for an important update to the answer!

Comment: @Philipp's comment works for me, too. Hopefully the answer will be edited. Thanks people!

Comment: I had to set the configuration parameter to `false` on OS X 10.10 and Git 2.0.0. I didn't have to clone nor checkout again. It just worked.

Comment: For me setting it to true (default on Git 2.2.0/Mac OS X 10.9.5) incorrectly shows 5 files with unusual names as untracked. 4 are shown surrounded by double quotes. If I set it to false, 4 of them are tracked but the one without double quotes remains untracked. The 4 probably have Korean characters, whilst the fifth has an umlaut. Any ideas?

Comment: This worked for me, although only after omitting `--global`.

Answer (score 37):

The cause is the different implementation of how the filesystem stores the file name.

In Unicode, Ü can be represented in two ways, one is by Ü alone, the other is by U + "combining umlaut character". A Unicode string can contain both forms, but as it's confusing to have both, the file system normalizes the unicode string by setting every umlauted-U to Ü, or U + "combining umlaut character".

Linux uses the former method, called Normal-Form-Composed (or NFC), and Mac OS X uses the latter method, called Normal-Form-Decomposed (NFD).

Apparently [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29) doesn't care about this point and simply uses the byte sequence of the filename, which leads to the problem you're having.

The mailing list thread *[Git, Mac OS X and German special characters](http://kerneltrap.org/mailarchive/git/2010/5/20/30759)* has a patch in it so that Git compares the file names after normalization.

Comment: Umlaut normalization is a huge mistake.  A file system should not be built in ways so things running on top have to "care" about strange modifications happening.  Ken Thompson would say this is not a feature, it's a symptom.  It can break virtually any system--not only git.  I've recently copied a web dump.  Umlaut normalization broke it, because an html file referenced an image with an umlaut in its file name.  I bet it's a security issue as well.

Comment: Actually, Linux does not always use NFC. Linux (as in the kernel and filesystems) just does not care and treats filenames as byte arrays. Normalization is up to the C library and applications; most use NFC, but that's only a convention.

Answer (score 11):

The following put in ~/.gitconfig works for me on 10.12.1 Sierra for UTF-8 names:

```
precomposeunicode = true
quotepath = false
```

The first option is needed so that git 'understands' UTF-8 and the second one so that it doesn't escape the characters.

Answer (score 5):

To make `git add file` work with umlauts in file names on Mac OS X, you may convert file path strings from composed into canonically decomposed UTF-8 using `iconv`.

```
# test case

mkdir testproject
cd testproject

git --version    # git version 1.7.6.1
locale charmap   # UTF-8

git init
file=$'\303\234berschrift.txt'    # composed UTF-8 (Linux-compatible)
touch "$file"
echo 'Hello, world!' > "$file"

# convert composed into canonically decomposed UTF-8
# cf. http://codesnippets.joyent.com/posts/show/12251
# printf '%s' "$file" | iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8-mac | LC_ALL=C vis -fotc 
#git add "$file"
git add "$(printf '%s' "$file" | iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8-mac)"  

git commit -a -m 'This is my commit message!'
git show
git status
git ls-files '*'
git ls-files -z '*' | tr '\0' '\n'

touch $'caf\303\251 1' $'caf\303\251 2' $'caf\303\251 3'
git ls-files --other '*'
git ls-files -z --other '*' | tr '\0' '\n'
```

Comment: I tried this, and couldn't make it work. It was still confused and unable to locate the file.

Answer (score 3):

Change the repository's OSX-specific `core.precomposeunicode` flag to true:

```
git config core.precomposeunicode.true
```

To make sure new repositories get that flag, also run:

```
git config --global core.precomposeunicode true
```

Here is the relevant snippet from the manpage:

> This option is only used by Mac OS implementation of Git. When
>   core.precomposeunicode=true, Git reverts the unicode decomposition of
>   filenames done by Mac OS. This is useful when sharing a repository
>   between Mac OS and Linux or Windows. (Git for Windows 1.7.10 or higher
>   is needed, or Git under cygwin 1.7). When false, file names are
>   handled fully transparent by Git, which is backward compatible with
>   older versions of Git.

Answer (score 2):

It is correct.

Your filename is in [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), Ü being represented as LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U + COMBINING DIAERESIS (Unicode 0x0308, utf8 0xcc 0x88) instead of LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS (Unicode 0x00dc, utf8 0xc3 0x9c). The [Mac OS X HFS file system decomposes Unicode in a such way](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn/tn1150.html#UnicodeSubtleties). [Git](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_%28software%29) in turn shows the octal-escape form of the non-ASCII filename bytes.

Note that Unicode filenames can make your repository non-portable. For example, [msysgit has had problems dealing with Unicode filenames](http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=230).

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with my personal repository, so I wrote a helper script with Python 3. You can grap it here: https://github.com/sjtoik/umlaut-cleaner

The script needs a bit of manual labour, but not much.