# Removing a file that looks like "\357\275\236"

Tags: git

When I do 
git status

```
# On branch inline
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   "\357\275\236"
# nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

However, when I do `ls -al`, I don't see anything that looks like `\357\275\236`

Comment: do you have a file with non-ascii characters? umlauts, kanji, etc.?

Comment: No I don't have non-ascii characters

Comment: The "\357\275\236" encoding is the unicode replacement character [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_%28Unicode_block%29#Replacement_character].  No idea why it appears in your context, unless you have a hardware problem.

Comment: @Rich It’s actually U+FF5E FULLWIDTH TILDE

Answer (score 5):

You likely have a file with UTF-8 characters in it's name. Run

> git config core.quotepath false

to change the behavior of git and show you the file name that the OS will likely present to you.

Here is a [workaround to deal with Mac OS X HFS+ UTF-8 encoded files and git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7322034/1309300)! The answer to this question also includes a good explanation.

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want that file and don't care about how to list it, just do:

```
git clean -df
```

That should get rid of it. Make sure you don't have any other work in progress. You could also inspect it with `git gui` for fun first.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Be careful with it. Better try a "dry run" first to see what is exactly removed. (--dry-run) 

It deleted also empty folders and non tracked-folders but it didn't delete the files with umlauts :-)

Answer (score 0):

I use **Smartgit UI** + **Msysgit** on Windows and **Bitbucket** as Remote repository.

Also I couldn't remove any non-ascii file name from my local repository

so I tried to **remove these files from Bitbucket** and **pull** source code to my local repository and it Worked!