# The correct way to create an app that is in a non-English language only

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, macos, cocoa

I need to create an iPhone/Mac app that is in a non-English language only. What’s the right way to do this? The app’s name even has some non-English (unicode) characters in it. I can separate the problem into three specific questions:

1. How should I deal with the fact that my app’s name is, say, “Déclaration”? I know I should probably not name my project Déclaration.xcodeproj from the start (e.g. because that makes output from `git` on the Terminal look painful). How should I set up my project?
2. How should I deal with `NSString`s in my code? Should I just write things like `NSString *labelTitle = @"Bienvenue à la déclaration!";` without any hesitation? I know that a more proper way would be to use localization techniques, but isn’t that too much pain, given that I only need the foreign language? It seems rather fishy having to make the whole app in English, even if I don’t need it.
3. Are there any other things I should take into consideration, when writing a non-English only app?

Comment: Marked up for clarity of question. Re part 2: There are a couple of tools supplied by apple to speed up the localisation process and I would look them up as they make the 'pain' much less than you might think especially if you are starting a new project you can start from scratch with NSLocalizedStrings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Don't worry about the Git output.  Mac filenames have been Unicode for a very long time now.  Git is using UTF-8 but it's cautious about printing out non-ASCII characters so it escapes them.  You can still do things like this:

   ```
   git init
   git add Déclaration.xcodeproj
   ```

   You can turn the escaping off using the `core.quotepath` setting:

   ```
   git config core.quotepath false
   ```
2. Yes, you do not need to hesitate.  You can always localize later, using strings in your native language as the starting point.
3. Yes, in the `Info.plist` change the "Localization native development region" to the language you are using instead of English.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to get `git` to show the unicode characters? That would make the whole experience great.

Comment: @Enchilada: `git config core.quotepath false`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in order to share git repositories with non-ASCII letters in file names, you need to set the core.precomposeunicode option to true on the Mac, before cloning the repository on the Mac:

```
git config --global core.precomposeunicode true
```

As described in [git config man page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html), the option is related to the particular decomposition of Unicode characters in Mac OS:

> This option is only used by Mac OS implementation of git. When core.precomposeunicode=true, git reverts the unicode decomposition of filenames done by Mac OS. This is useful when sharing a repository between Mac OS and Linux or Windows. (Git for Windows 1.7.10 or higher is needed, or git under cygwin 1.7). When false, file names are handled fully transparent by git, which is backward compatible with older versions of git.

Reference:
[Answer by Leo Koppelkamm in "Git and the Umlaut problem on Mac OS X"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15553796/207968)