# git-pull: could not detach HEAD for Unicode filenames

Tags: git, unicode, osx-leopard

I run this git pull command and it chokes on the Unicode file names

```
& git pull
From . 
  * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
    test-sample-files/MByte/CJK-UTF8-MultiByte/樣品套裝/サンプル.java
    test-sample-files/MByte/CJK-UTF8-MultiByte/樣品套裝/의 견본을 뽑다.java
    test-sample-files/MByte/japanese/これはサンプルのテストであり、できるだけ早く修正する必要があります.java
    test-sample-files/MByte/japanese/サンプル.java
    test-sample-files/MByte/korean/의 견본을 뽑다.java
Please move or remove them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
could not detach HEAD
```

However a git status reports the working directory clean

```
$ git status
# On branch dev/experimental
# Your branch and 'master' have diverged,
# and have 3 and 96 different commit(s) each, respectively.
#
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

no "git add", or "git reset" or "rm ...*" does resolve the situation. Any help is much appreciated.

P.S.: I'm running "git version 1.7.5.4" on Mac OS X Leopard (10.5), which is the latest pre-build I could find for leopard.

Comment: Wow. Can you actually have a class named 의 견본을 뽑다? That's pretty cool.

Answer (score 3):

Your files are untracked in the current state of your working tree. That's why `git add` or `git rm` doesn't do anything.

Stash them with `git stash save --untracked`, they will be saved in a stash. After pull you can restore with `git stash pop` but you might have conflicts them since the pull will have checked theme out at a possible different content.

Since you're stuck with Git 1.7.5 `stash` doesn't know the `--untracked` option, so you can

- move untracked files to a temp directory, and restore them:

  ```
   git ls-files --other --exclude-standard | xargs -t -I file  mv file untracked
  ```
- Or add them with `git add -u`, and commit

Comment: Thanks Charles, unfortunately mu version of git does not have the option of stash save --untracked.

Comment: that's too bad, you can try to install 1.7.10 with [howebrew](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/)

Answer (score 2):

The cause for this is described in stack overflow already and a [workaround to handle Mac OS X UTF-8 encoded file names with git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7322034/1309300)! is described as well.