# Git says that some of my image files are untracked (they are not)

Tags: macos, git, version-control, png

## Summary

I have a problem where 160 (out of 3 605) image files show up as being "untracked" by Git, but I know that these files are, in fact, tracked. When cloning the repository anew, these files are included.

**This only happens on my Mac** (*OS X 10.8.4*). I'm using *Git version 1.7.12.4 (Apple Git-37)*. It works fine in my Windows 8 VM and on other computers (verified with a coworkers).

## Details

```
git status

# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   [ List of "untracked" .png's ]
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

A few relevant facts about this particular repository:

- There are no `.gitignore`, `.gitattributes` or `.gitconfig` files.
- There is currently only 1 branch (`master`), with only 1 initial commit.
- There used to be a remote branch where a bunch of files were deleted. This branch was eventually deleted (by me); it was never merged anywhere.
- I have made no (intentional) local changes to any files in this repository.

Amongst other things, I've tried this:

```
git rm --cached -r .

git reset --hard

git status
```

The same list of "untracked" files is displayed (complete list in edited section below).

```
git ls-files "[ one_of_the_untracked_pngs ]" --error-unmatch

error: pathspec '"[ one_of_the_untracked_pngs ]"' did not match any file(s) known to git.
Did you forget to 'git add'?
```

Each of the files appear to be untracked, but they definitely exist in the remote repository.

I've also tried deleting and re-cloning the repository, to no avail. All other Git repositories I have cloned on the same computer are behaving as expected.

## Edits (after comments and further investigation)

I discovered a few `.jpg`'s in the midst of all the `.png`'s, so it doesn't seem to be an issue with filetype (my initial though). After Joachim's comment, I started thinking about casing.

The paths and names of the affected files are all different in some way, but I haven't been able to discern a common pattern. The paths and filenames used is best described as arbitrary.

Here the full list of affected files:

```
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/_thumbs/Filer til artikler/.thumbnails/Ra\314\212det.PNG"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/_thumbs/Filer til artikler/.w100/Ra\314\212det.PNG"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/_thumbs/Filer til artikler/.w275/Ra\314\212det.PNG"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/_thumbs/Filer til artikler/.web/Ra\314\212det.PNG"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/_thumbs/Filer til artikler/Ra\314\212det.PNG"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/article/.thumbnails/Ra\314\212det.PNG"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/article/.w100/Ra\314\212det.PNG"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/article/.w275/Ra\314\212det.PNG"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/article/.web/Ra\314\212det.PNG"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/article/Ra\314\212det.PNG"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/tab1/article/lA\314\203\302\270ssalg"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/tab1/file/.thumbnails/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/tab1/file/.w100/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/tab1/file/.w275/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/tab1/file/.web/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/tab1/file/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/tab2/_thumbs/Filer generlt/.thumbnails/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/tab2/_thumbs/Filer generlt/.w100/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/tab2/_thumbs/Filer generlt/.w275/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/tab2/_thumbs/Filer generlt/.web/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/tab2/_thumbs/Filer generlt/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/tab2/file/.thumbnails/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/tab2/file/.w100/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/tab2/file/.w275/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/tab2/file/.web/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/tab2/file/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/tab3/file/.thumbnails/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/tab3/file/.w100/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/tab3/file/.w275/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/tab3/file/.web/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/tab3/file/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/tab4/file/.thumbnails/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/tab4/file/.w100/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/tab4/file/.w275/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/tab4/file/.web/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/tab4/file/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/tab5/_thumbs/Filer generlt/.thumbnails/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/tab5/_thumbs/Filer generlt/.w100/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/tab5/_thumbs/Filer generlt/.w275/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/tab5/_thumbs/Filer generlt/.web/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/tab5/_thumbs/Filer generlt/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/tab5/file/.thumbnails/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/tab5/file/.w100/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/tab5/file/.w275/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/tab5/file/.web/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/tab5/file/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/tab6/file/.thumbnails/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/tab6/file/.w100/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/tab6/file/.w275/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/tab6/file/.web/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/tab6/file/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/tab7/file/.thumbnails/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/tab7/file/.w100/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/tab7/file/.w275/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/tab7/file/.web/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/PreIntegreringAvInnholdsversjoner/novus/upload/tab7/file/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/novus 2011.05.03/upload/_thumbs/Filer til artikler/.thumbnails/Ra\314\212det.PNG"
"old/novus 2011.05.03/upload/_thumbs/Filer til artikler/.w100/Ra\314\212det.PNG"
"old/novus 2011.05.03/upload/_thumbs/Filer til artikler/.w275/Ra\314\212det.PNG"
"old/novus 2011.05.03/upload/_thumbs/Filer til artikler/Ra\314\212det.PNG"
"old/novus 2011.05.03/upload/article/.thumbnails/Ra\314\212det.PNG"
"old/novus 2011.05.03/upload/article/.w100/Ra\314\212det.PNG"
"old/novus 2011.05.03/upload/article/.w275/Ra\314\212det.PNG"
"old/novus 2011.05.03/upload/article/Ra\314\212det.PNG"
"old/novus 2011.05.03/upload/tab1/article/lA\314\203\302\270ssalg"
"old/novus 2011.05.03/upload/tab1/file/.thumbnails/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/novus 2011.05.03/upload/tab1/file/.w100/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/novus 2011.05.03/upload/tab1/file/.w275/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/novus 2011.05.03/upload/tab1/file/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/novus 2011.05.03/upload/tab2/_thumbs/Filer generlt/.thumbnails/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/novus 2011.05.03/upload/tab2/_thumbs/Filer generlt/.w100/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/novus 2011.05.03/upload/tab2/_thumbs/Filer generlt/.w275/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/novus 2011.05.03/upload/tab2/_thumbs/Filer generlt/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/novus 2011.05.03/upload/tab2/file/.thumbnails/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/novus 2011.05.03/upload/tab2/file/.w100/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/novus 2011.05.03/upload/tab2/file/.w275/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/novus 2011.05.03/upload/tab2/file/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/novus 2011.05.03/upload/tab3/file/.thumbnails/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/novus 2011.05.03/upload/tab3/file/.w100/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/novus 2011.05.03/upload/tab3/file/.w275/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/novus 2011.05.03/upload/tab3/file/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/novus 2011.05.03/upload/tab4/file/.thumbnails/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/novus 2011.05.03/upload/tab4/file/.w100/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/novus 2011.05.03/upload/tab4/file/.w275/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/novus 2011.05.03/upload/tab4/file/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/novus 2011.05.03/upload/tab5/_thumbs/Filer generlt/.thumbnails/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/novus 2011.05.03/upload/tab5/_thumbs/Filer generlt/.w100/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/novus 2011.05.03/upload/tab5/_thumbs/Filer generlt/.w275/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/novus 2011.05.03/upload/tab5/_thumbs/Filer generlt/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/novus 2011.05.03/upload/tab5/file/.thumbnails/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/novus 2011.05.03/upload/tab5/file/.w100/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/novus 2011.05.03/upload/tab5/file/.w275/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/novus 2011.05.03/upload/tab5/file/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/novus 2011.05.03/upload/tab6/file/.thumbnails/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/novus 2011.05.03/upload/tab6/file/.w100/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/novus 2011.05.03/upload/tab6/file/.w275/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/novus 2011.05.03/upload/tab6/file/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/novus 2011.05.03/upload/tab7/file/.thumbnails/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/novus 2011.05.03/upload/tab7/file/.w100/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/novus 2011.05.03/upload/tab7/file/.w275/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"old/novus 2011.05.03/upload/tab7/file/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"www/html/v1/gfx/hgra\314\212bg.jpg"
"www/html/v1/gfx/sta\314\212endebilde.jpg"
"www/novus/upload/_thumbs/Filer til artikler/.thumbnails/Ra\314\212det.PNG"
"www/novus/upload/_thumbs/Filer til artikler/.w100/Ra\314\212det.PNG"
"www/novus/upload/_thumbs/Filer til artikler/.w275/Ra\314\212det.PNG"
"www/novus/upload/_thumbs/Filer til artikler/.web/Ra\314\212det.PNG"
"www/novus/upload/_thumbs/Filer til artikler/Ra\314\212det.PNG"
"www/novus/upload/article/.thumbnails/Ra\314\212det.PNG"
"www/novus/upload/article/.w100/Ra\314\212det.PNG"
"www/novus/upload/article/.w275/Ra\314\212det.PNG"
"www/novus/upload/article/.web/Ra\314\212det.PNG"
"www/novus/upload/article/Ra\314\212det.PNG"
"www/novus/upload/tab1/article/lA\314\203\302\270ssalg"
"www/novus/upload/tab1/file/.thumbnails/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"www/novus/upload/tab1/file/.w100/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"www/novus/upload/tab1/file/.w275/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"www/novus/upload/tab1/file/.web/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"www/novus/upload/tab1/file/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"www/novus/upload/tab2/_thumbs/Filer generlt/.thumbnails/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"www/novus/upload/tab2/_thumbs/Filer generlt/.w100/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"www/novus/upload/tab2/_thumbs/Filer generlt/.w275/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"www/novus/upload/tab2/_thumbs/Filer generlt/.web/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"www/novus/upload/tab2/_thumbs/Filer generlt/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"www/novus/upload/tab2/file/.thumbnails/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"www/novus/upload/tab2/file/.w100/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"www/novus/upload/tab2/file/.w275/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"www/novus/upload/tab2/file/.web/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"www/novus/upload/tab2/file/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"www/novus/upload/tab3/file/.thumbnails/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"www/novus/upload/tab3/file/.w100/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"www/novus/upload/tab3/file/.w275/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"www/novus/upload/tab3/file/.web/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"www/novus/upload/tab3/file/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"www/novus/upload/tab4/file/.thumbnails/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"www/novus/upload/tab4/file/.w100/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"www/novus/upload/tab4/file/.w275/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"www/novus/upload/tab4/file/.web/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"www/novus/upload/tab4/file/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"www/novus/upload/tab5/_thumbs/Filer generlt/.thumbnails/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"www/novus/upload/tab5/_thumbs/Filer generlt/.w100/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"www/novus/upload/tab5/_thumbs/Filer generlt/.w275/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"www/novus/upload/tab5/_thumbs/Filer generlt/.web/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"www/novus/upload/tab5/_thumbs/Filer generlt/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"www/novus/upload/tab5/file/.thumbnails/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"www/novus/upload/tab5/file/.w100/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"www/novus/upload/tab5/file/.w275/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"www/novus/upload/tab5/file/.web/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"www/novus/upload/tab5/file/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"www/novus/upload/tab6/file/.thumbnails/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"www/novus/upload/tab6/file/.w100/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"www/novus/upload/tab6/file/.w275/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"www/novus/upload/tab6/file/.web/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"www/novus/upload/tab6/file/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"www/novus/upload/tab7/file/.thumbnails/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"www/novus/upload/tab7/file/.w100/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"www/novus/upload/tab7/file/.w275/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"www/novus/upload/tab7/file/.web/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
"www/novus/upload/tab7/file/500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png"
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening? Help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just to make sure you're saying what I think you're saying, do you mean that a clean clone to an empty directory has the same problem? I seem to remember that a reset will not reset casing of files correctly, and since MacOS is case insensitive and git a bit randomly case sensitive, it may cause trouble.

Comment: Yes, a clean clone to an empty directory has the same problem, but only under Mac OS X. Thanks for the tips about casing issues; it gave me a few new theories to test.

Comment: Edited to add more detail and the full list of all affected files.

Comment: What happens if you explicitly `git add` one of those files?

Comment: I was able to `git add .` and commit them all as normal, resulting in a clean working directory. And the file did not get added twice in my working tree. Interestingly, it said `create mode 100644` in front of each file in the commit log; I didn't notice that before.

Comment: All those files seem to have non-ascii characters in the filenames.  Are the files that are "working" correctly limited to ASCII characters only?  Incidentally, what should "Flag_of_A\314\212land" be?

Comment: Yes that's what I was going to say. The \314 is a I with a grave mark over it. Maybe some issue with the representation of the file names on different computers? You could try changing to "normal" ASCII chars?

Comment: Thanks for the help! This is a very old codebase from Norway, so there are a lot of Norwegian characters in filenames. @msandiford: _'500px-Flag_of_A\314\212land_svg.png'_ should actually be '_500px-Flag_of_ÅÅand_svg.png'_.

Comment: @pcm: I will check if the files that are working are all ASCII. I think _Å_ should be `/182` from the Extended ASCII character set (not `\314\212`). Can't believe I didn't think about that earlier.

I could probably change the filenames (or just adding and committing them). But it would be nice to understand why this is happening and find the "right way" to fix it.

It seems a bit odd that the characters in the filenames affects Git, since Git tries to be platform and filesystem independent. I was hoping that maybe there is a way to fix this without changing the files.

Comment: Right. I did some more checking and that definitely seems to be the cause. All the affected files erroneously contain either `\314\203\302\270` (supposed to be `Ø`) or `\314\212` (supposed to be `Å`). I've got no idea how that happened.

I'm still wonder why this is only happening on OS X. And what would be a good way to fix it? I'm not very adept at dealing with this breed of problems (yet).

Comment: Aha! I just found my answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581857/git-and-the-umlaut-problem-on-mac-os-x

How can I close this question as a duplicate?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved this problem by doing this:

```
git config --global core.precomposeunicode true
```

And then re-cloning the repository.

(See [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15553796/195964) for more details about the cause, etc.).