# Inside a script, git cannot add to the index filenames with accented letters

Tags: macos, git, scripting

I have a git cli wrapper that I use from inside a nodejs application, and I recently noticed that when I try to add files which have a name with non ASCII characters in it, like `tèst.ò`, those files are simply not added. No errors are generated. If I try to add a file which does not exist, an error is generated.

I created the very minimal test case, which consists of just a line inside a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

git add "èè.md"
```

and it fails as well. Note that on a couple of Linux boxes I own, it works.

What is happening?

git is 1.7.x, OSX is 10.9.3.

Comment: Seems OK with git 1.9 and git 2.0

I really hope that it is not a git problem because I cannot "ship" git as part of my project...

Comment: This is probably related but in my case, command line works.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581857/git-and-the-umlaut-problem-on-mac-os-x

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with git < 1.8.5.x

Any other git version works. Solved upgrading git.