# OSX 10.10 filename encoding versus git

Tags: macos, git

I have a file "Le Rêve" in my git repository, with the e-circumflex being the important bit.

Under my old OS X 10.9 box, under my colleague's OS X 10.10 box, and a windows box, there were no issues caused by the filename.

Under my brand-new OS X 10.10 box, I cloned the repository and git tells me:

```
Untracked files:
[...]
"Le-R\303\252ve-The-Dream-By-Pablo-Picasso.jpg"
```

With a `git clean -fd` I get:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
[...]
deleted:    "Le-Re\314\202ve-The-Dream-By-Pablo-Picasso.jpg"
```

With a `git checkout -f --` I go back to the initial state, with the e-circumflex encoded as `\303\252` and thus being a new file.

This issue seemed to be similar to:
[Git and the Umlaut problem on Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581857/git-and-the-umlaut-problem-on-mac-os-x)
but following that answer did not change the behaviour I see (I tried "git config core.precomposeunicode true" and again with a --global).

Any ideas what caused this change?

Comment: Are you using different Git version on these machines? In particular, the "Apple Git" that ships with XCode is usually outdated. Better use https://sourceforge.net/projects/git-osx-installer/files/.

Comment: And where does your git binary come from?

Comment: I'm using git 1.9.3 on my new machine, it's the Apple git.

I was using the Apple git on my old machine running 10.8 and 10.9, but I can't check what version since that machine walked off.  Pretty sure my colleague is using Apple git on his machine.