How to fix directory umlauts with git and powershell?
I would like to add a directory to git. Inside the directory i have a directory named "Archivierung und Löschung" (german umlauts).
If i'm doing a git init and a git status it shows me (on Win Powerhshell):
"Archivierung und L\303\266schung/"
$PSCulture is set to "de-DE".
How can i fix this?
I have tried to fix it with:
git config --global i18n.commitEncoding utf8
also tried with
git config --global i18n.commitEncoding cp1252
I think i need to fix it on another place.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34549040/git-not-displaying-unicode-file-names

@Kim Thanks a lot. This i haven't seen in the docs.

Kims proposal to use git config core.quotePath false was the perfect solution for my issue.
